# How to fix `Implementation of 'Protocol' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension`?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I'm getting a compiler error while adding new protocol conformance to an extension.

```
struct EquatableStruct { }

extension EquatableStruct: Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: EquatableStruct, rhs: EquatableStruct) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

Here I'm getting the compiler error:

> `Implementation of 'Equatable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension`

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Why have you completely changed your question? It makes existing answers pointless and your updated code doesn't actually produce the error you posted.

Comment: Same question different protocol

Comment: No, the new code doesn't cause any errors. And you've made my answer obsolete.

Comment: Your answer is not what I want. I know `Comparable` extends from `Equatable`. Even if I confirm to `Equatable` I get the same error. There is no misquote in error here. i need to know the reason why i'm getting the error that i've quoted.

Comment: The newest code in your question does not give any error. I copied and pasted your exact code into an Xcode 9.4 (Swift 4.1) playground and it compiles just fine after adding one dummy property to the struct. The original code you posted did have the problem and it was solved as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misquoting the error. It should be:

> Implementation of 'Equatable' cannot be automatically synthesized in an extension

`Comparable` extends `Equatable`. If you want your extension to conform to `Comparable` you must also implement the `Equatable` protocol.

```
extension ComparableStruct: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: ComparableStruct, rhs: ComparableStruct) -> Bool {
        return true // FIX
    }

    static func == (lhs: ComparableStruct, rhs: ComparableStruct) -> Bool {
        return true // FIX
    }
}
```